# How to retrieve the most recent records for all ids when grouped by date

Tags: mysql

I need a mysql query that will take the most recent record for each of my ids when grouped by date even if the record isn't associated with the date. I am not sure if this is possible with mysql but I appreciate any help you can give.

For example, let's say I have the following table:

```
user_id | total | timestamp
----------------------------
   1    |   -15 | jan 1
   2    |    -5 | jan 1
   3    |   -10 | jan 1
   1    |    -4 | jan 2
   3    |   -16 | jan 3
```

I would like it to return the following table:

```
user_id | total | timestamp
----------------------------
   1    |   -15 | jan 1
   2    |    -5 | jan 1
   3    |   -10 | jan 1
   1    |    -4 | jan 2
   2    |    -5 | jan 2
   3    |   -10 | jan 2
   1    |    -4 | jan 3
   2    |    -5 | jan 3
   3    |   -16 | jan 3
```

Please let me know if you need additional clarification.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: paste ur `query` too...

Comment: `even if the record isn't associated with the date` means the timestamp column can be null?

Comment: The timestamp column is not null. All records have a timestamp, but i don't care about the actual date on the results table as long as it is less than the group date. Does that make sense?

Comment: how can you return `2 | -5 | jan 2` its not in the input table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2177/10)

```
select user_id,

(select total 
        from t 
      where user_id=t2.user_id 
            and t.timestamp <= t2.timestamp 
 order by t.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) as total,

timestamp
from
(
select user_id,timestamp
from
(select distinct user_id from t) t0
cross join
(select distinct timestamp from t) t1
) t2

order by timestamp,user_id
```